# como puedo el error?= invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration and invalid token '(' in class, struct, or

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TrackerLibrary {
  public class TeamModel {
     // Aqui estan los errores
    public List< PersonModel > TeamMembers { get; set; } = new List< PersonModel >( );
    public string TeamName { get; set; }                 
  }
}
```

- Error 1:

  > Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
- Error 2:

  > Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: los espacios que se visualizan en el codigo publicados estan tambien en tu codigo? apunto los que estan junto al < o el espacio en el ( ), podrias ver de quitarlos

Comment: No, en el codigo no estan los espacios. Sigue dando error en el '=' y '('

Comment: Si mal y no recuerdo, crear una propiedad y asignarle un valor por default estan desde C#6. ¿Podrias especificar que version de framework y visual studio estas usando?.

Answer (score 4):

Intenta usando

```
public class TeamModel 
{
    public List<PersonModel> TeamMembers { get; set; } 
    public string TeamName { get; set; }  

    public TeamModel()
    {
        this. TeamMembers = new List<PersonModel>( );
    }
}
```

En este caso asignas la instancia en el constructor de la clase cuando se instancia

La caracteristica que quieres usar es de `C# 6`

[C# 6 features – Auto-property initializers](https://csharp.today/c-6-features-auto-property-initializers/)

por lo que tendrias que estar usando `.net framework 4.6`

[C# and .Net Version History](https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-dot-net-version-history.html)

Comment: Lo cambie asi y ya no da error, y puede que tengas razon porque tengo el .net framework 4.0 por lo que tendria que instanciar en el constructor, una pregunta tengo el visual studio 2010 podria actualizar el .net framework a 4.6?

Comment: si revisas el ultimo link que puse en la respuesta veras que no puedes, deberias pasarte al VS 2013 o 2015